# How to submit REST request without refresh of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, rest

I have this php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Set variables
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
    $hotelID = 1;
    $userName = 'admin';
    $password = 'admin';
    $url = 'serviceurl/goes/here';
    $requestTime = date('d.m.Y H:i:s');
    $tempFromDate = date_create($_POST['fromDate']);
    $tempToDate = date_create($_POST['toDate']);
    $fromDate = date_format($tempFromDate, 'd.m.Y H:i:s' );
    $toDate = date_format($tempToDate, 'd.m.Y H:i:s' );
    $token = md5('some_token');
    $data = array(
        'Content-Encoding: chunked',
        'Transfer-Encoding: chunked',
        'fromDate: ' . $fromDate,
        'toDate: ' . $toDate,
        'hotelID: ' . $hotelID,
        'requestTime: ' . $requestTime,
        'userName:' . $userName,
        'token: ' . $token,
    );

    //Start cURL and set options
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //If there are errors, save and display them
    if (!$response) {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $result = json_decode($response,true);
        curl_close($ch);
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

It submits a request to a service, that returns a JSON response. This works, as I get the results I need. Problem is, I need to  be able to submit this request and then display more fields with the data I get, without page refresh. My form looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-inline" id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fromDate">From Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="toDate">To Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="toDate" id="toDate" required>
    </div>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $result['Status'] === 'OK') {
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rooms">Choose Room</label>
        <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
            <option value='<?php echo $result['Content'][0]['TypeName']; ?>'><?php echo $result['Content'][0]['TypeName']; ?></option>
            <option value='<?php echo $result['Content'][1]['TypeName']; ?>'><?php echo $result['Content'][1]['TypeName']; ?></option>
            <option value='<?php echo $result['Content'][2]['TypeName']; ?>'><?php echo $result['Content'][2]['TypeName']; ?></option>
            <option value='<?php echo $result['Content'][3]['TypeName']; ?>'><?php echo $result['Content'][3]['TypeName']; ?></option>
            <option value='<?php echo $result['Content'][4]['TypeName']; ?>'><?php echo $result['Content'][4]['TypeName']; ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="people">Adults</label>
        <select name="people" id="people">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="names">Names</label>
            <input type="text" id="names">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telephone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" id="telephone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="notes">Notes</label>
            <textarea name="notes" id="notes" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Check availability</button>
</form>
```

I know jquery/ajax should come into play, but so far, everything I try, does not work. Request to the service does not get submitted. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: So you want to know how to submit a form using ajax? [link](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zWZFV5Qfy5n4BtiWp-gE#q=Javascript+form+ajax)

Comment: Idea is I need to pass the fromDate and toDate to the php code via ajax without a refresh, and then display the result that means more form fields that are populated with the returned data.  I do this now, but with a page refresh (see the dropdown menu, it is populated by the returned array from the request). I tried some examples that were shown, but in my use case, they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

hmm...

I think you can use jQuery to send AJAX to server, and use JS to edit your website(just print in console is ok too)

jQuery Post: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

and You need to know some Ajax knowledge.

Comment: I use this to post the data with ajax:
`$(function () {

        $('#form').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'index.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert('a');
                }
            });

        });

    });`
Still nothing gets posted. I get the alert that post data is submitted, but in reality it does not submit. I get an array in the body if I submit normally and I get nothing with this